# En ubuntu 18 los procesos de node js no se detienen y sospecho que es por el PM2

Tags: nodejs, pm2, port, kill

Tengo 5 aplicaciones de NodeJS funcionando en el mismo servidor con Ubuntu Server 18.04 de 64 bits, como microservicios y los gestiono con PM2. Cuando voy a realizar cambios, detengo el proceso de PM2 y luego lo ejecuto con `node server.js`, para monitorear los cambios y actualizaciones del código. Si embargo, usando el VSC, creo que he cerrado el editor aun corriendo el microservicio desde la consola con `node server.js` o con el Debugger de VSC usando el plugin `ts-node-dev`, y si trato de ejecutar `node server.js`, me indica que el puerto 9001 ya esta ocupado; luego trato de eliminar el proceso usando `kill -9 PID`, **pero cuando hago esto de inmediato se crea un nuevo proceso con un PId diferente y así sucesivamente**.

Cómo puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

a mi me paso algo parecido y uso

```
killall -s KILL node
```

Comment: Muchas. gracias, pero tengo una pregunta: este comando lo que hace es eliminar todos los procesos abiertos por Node ?